# Can Netty send/receive more than 1024 bytes per frame over TCP with SSL?

Tags: java, netty

**SOLUTION: Using a [ChannelTrafficShapingHandler](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/traffic/ChannelTrafficShapingHandler.html);**

<s>**Problem**
It appears that my implementation Netty (version 4.1.25Final) cannot send or receive more than 1024 bytes of data per second on average.</s>

**Question**
Is it possible to send/receive more than 1024 bytes per second using TCP and a SSL? If so, how?

**Server Implementation**

```
 @Override
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

    SslHandler handler = context.newHandler(ch.alloc());

    handler.setHandshakeTimeoutMillis(20_000);
    handler.setCloseNotifyFlushTimeoutMillis(20_000);
    handler.setCloseNotifyReadTimeoutMillis(20_000);

    pipeline.addLast(handler);
    pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(1024 * 1024, 0, 8, 0, 8));
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new ByteArrayDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldPrepender(8));
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new ByteArrayEncoder());
    pipeline.addLast("handler", new ServerInboundHandler());
}
```

**Client Implementation**

```
    @Override
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

    pipeline.addLast(context.newHandler(ch.alloc(), "localhost", 1337));
    pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(1024 * 1024, 0, 8, 0, 8));
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new ByteArrayDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldPrepender(8));
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new ByteArrayEncoder());

    pipeline.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
    pipeline.addLast("handler", new ClientLoginChannelHandler(application, application.getPacketManager()));
}
```

It is worth noting that I have the following enabled;

```
// Server
.option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)

// Client
.option(ChannelOption.RCVBUF_ALLOCATOR, new DefaultMaxBytesRecvByteBufAllocator(1024 * 1024, 1024 * 1024))
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 1024 * 1024)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
```

Comment: So where the solution using the ChannelTrafficShapingHandler?
I had a similar problem I was developing TCP client and the xml that was from the server was cut off on 1024 byte, I was trying to figure out what is wrong, and adding 

.option(ChannelOption.RCVBUF_ALLOCATOR, new DefaultMaxBytesRecvByteBufAllocator(1024 * 1024, 1024 * 1024))

helped me, but I'm still curious about ChannelTrafficShapingHandler and how it can help me in this situation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, you need to accumulate data in channelRead() and invoke read() on channel before return from channelRead(). When there is no more data, your channelReadComplete() will be invoked and there is a moment when you send your accumulated data to your response handler.

Comment: I apologize, the resolve was using a ChannelTrafficShapingHandler which is the intended solution.